# Alert to warn site owner when content is outof date

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, publishing-site, alert, publishing-page

Any idea how I can set an alert to warn site owner if content is out of date?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest the use of native policies (like in our case the expiration policy) that you can attach to a specific content type and trigger an action / workflow when the policy is met. In this case it will be when an item's age is reached. (eg : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262112%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

What I've been doing for a customer is a custom field "review date" which allow them to pick a date when the content should be reviewed (because different type of content got different life time and even within the same content type it was not consistent) associated with a daily timer job that was looking for item reaching the dreaded date. As soon as found, it was sending an email to the content creator with a cc to the site collection administrator.

Answer (score 1):

http://vogtland.ws/markedwardvogt/?p=750

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointworkflow/thread/404d5023-25e2-4ae1-a414-af89ab1084bd

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010setup/thread/010a581b-3dd8-47b0-8f91-e0e5ecf7e201/

http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint_blank/archive/2009/07/20/automated-sharepoint-alerts-triggered-by-an-expiration-date.aspx

http://specmgt.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/documentexpiry/

http://weblogs.asp.net/sreejukg/archive/2010/11/11/retention-policy-for-document-library-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Comment: FYI.. you can edit your answer to add more information. Also, thanks for the helpful links but as I mentioned on your other answer.. we prefer if you include the relevant information in your answer and use the link as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

You should first think on what actually is the 'Content' you want to set alerts.

If they are records in document library\ lists, You can set retention policy. First, Create a workflow for the list to send email to the site owner. Now, under information management policies, you can Enable Retention > Add a retention stage > Set date to expire>Under actions, select start workflow> Select workflow to send email alert.

If they are lists\sites, you can create a custom timer job to scan the content and send emails.